# Find an example of a group morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Find an example of a group morphism $f : G_1 \to G_2$ such that $H_1 ◅ G_1$ and $f(H_1)$ is not normal in $G_2$.

How would you go about answering this question?

Answer (score 2):

Take $G_1=S_3$, $G_2=S_4$, $H_1=A_3=\{(1),(123),(132)\}$ and $f$ the natural embedding of $S_3$ in $S_4$.

Comment: I don't understand..

Comment: What exactly you do not understand? $A_3$ is not normal in $S_4$?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the natural embedding of S3 in S4'?

Comment: Ah, OK. Well, you can view $S_3$ as a subset of $S_4$. So your $f$ would be $f(\sigma)=\sigma$. This embedding is obviously a (trivial) homomorphism. That is, the elements of $S_3$ are then part of a bigger group in which $H_1$ loses its normality.

Comment: How does this show that f(H1) is not normal in G2?

Comment: This is something you yourself should find out! Hint - find an element of $S_4$, say $\tau$, such that $\tau^{-1}(123)\tau \notin A_3$. That is not too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Take $G_1=\{e, (12)(34), (13)(24),(14)(23)\}$, the abelian subgroup of $A_4$ isomorphic to Klein's Vierergruppe. It is a normal subgroup of $A_4$ and of $S_4$.

However, its subgroup $\langle\,(12)(34)\,\rangle$ while being normal in $V$, is not normal in $A_4$, since its conjugates, besides itself, are $\langle\,(13)(24)\,\rangle$ and $\langle\,(14)(23)\,\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

An idea to construct many counterexamples: Take $H_1=G_1$ and $G_2 = H \rtimes G_1$. Then, there is a natural monomorphism $\varphi : G_1 \to G_2 = H \rtimes G_1$, and $\varphi(H_1)$ is a normal subgroup if and only if $H \rtimes G_1 = H \times G_1$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Relation_to_direct_products)).